# Command line: Create new repository(group) / a repository(project) inside an existing repo group in RhodeCode (uses Hg Mercurial)

Tags: command-line, repository, project, command-line-interface, rhodecode

I'm looking for a way to create a new repository "newrepo" and a new project "newproject" in RhodeCode using command line way (instead of using RhodeCode Browser based GUI clicks).

RhodeCode version is 2.2.5 and it got all repositories/projects (after we migrated from Hg Mercurial to RhodeCode interface). Everything works great for the migrated projects or if I create a new repository/project inside an existing repository manually using RhodeCode GUI interface.

Now, I want to do create a new repository / project using a command line CLI/API way so that I can automate the repository/project creation process (from Jenkins).

I searched a bit and found that I have to use the following link but couldn't find an easy example on how to actually run it: https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/api/api.html#create-repo

Has anyone of you tried to create a new repository in RhodeCode using a Shell script or groovy etc? Thanks.

**PS**: I'm not looking for creating a new Hg/Mercurial repository (hg init, then hg push / hg pull etc).

Automation I'm trying would do this:

1. Create a new repo / project or a new repository group then repository in it. Probably grant some access to a set of users/groups or create one etc. Also create an empty README / DELETE_ME_ANYTIME file automatically.
2. Once the above is created, then I'll create a project structure locally on my machine and perform **hg push** to the above mentioned newly created repository/project or repositorygroup/repository whatever you call it.

   *hg clone http://e100020@servermerc.hola.company.com:8010/newrepo/newproject*

   *hg add README # add first file*

   *hg commit -m "Initial" # commit with message*

   *hg push  # push changes back*
3. Auto create Jenkins build / etc jobs and auto launch the first build and be done with it.

I know how to do bullet 2, 3 automatically (using template job formats etc, in Jenkins and running Maven/Gradle build to build the project) but the 1st bullet is what I'm trying to find, how to do at command line?

For bullet 1: I found this.

**rhodecode-api**

The RhodeCode API lets you connect to RhodeCode Enterprise and carry out management tasks, for more information about the API, see the API Documentation. To pass arguments on the comamnd-line use the method:option syntax.

Example usage:

```
# Run the get_repos API call and sample output
$ rhodecode-api --instance-name=enterprise-1 create_repo repo_name:brand-new repo_type:hg description:repo-desc
{
  "error": null,
  "id": 1110,
  "result": {
    "msg": "Created new repository `brand-new`",
    "success": true,
    "task": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution using our api helper is the best. I would also recommend using auth-tokens for jenkins API calls, as well as the push operations. You this way have much more control over the credentials, and auth-tokens can be easily revokable. They work in similar way as googles application-specific passwords.